# How to test a target component when it refers to other components' state when it renders

Tags: react-redux, jestjs

I am writing jest tests. The tested Dashboard component's render shows below,

in Dashboard.jsx

```
render(){
    const {appState,dashboardState,shopFiltersState,shopSortersState}=store.getState();
    return (
        <div style={appState.primeStyle.dashboard}>
        {
            (appState.currUser.account==='admin')?
                <IconButton iconStyle={shopDetailStyle.iconMenu.icon} style={shopDetailStyle.iconMenu.iconBtn} tooltip={I18n.t('moreInfo')} tooltipPosition="top-center" onClick={this.handleIconAPClick} ><IconInfo /></IconButton>:<div/>

        }
        </div>
    );

}
```

If I want to test this Dashboard.jsx with different appState, shopFiterssState or shopSortersState, are there good suggestions about how to do it?

I know the existence of mockStore, but I don't think it can be used to modify other component's state in the normal code flow.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: If you use connect inside of getState, you can inject the state as props for testing.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect. It's a form of dependency inversion, if you don't get the state *inside* the component you're less tightly coupled to it.